# Downloading Spring-Boot-Starter-Project from Sonatype Repo Manager

Tags: maven, spring-boot, proxy, sonatype

I'm getting the error, when adding/creating a Spring-Boot-Starter-Project to my Eclipse workbench:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo-2:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.4.RELEASE from https://
 repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
 org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.4.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

This probably comes up because I'm sitting behind our company proxy.

The proxy is not getting any requests from my eclipse. I've read about that already, it seems to be a bug in eclipse.

I've tried to setup the proxy in Eclipse:

Window > Preferences > Generel > Network Connections

Manual:
- with given credentials for HTTP and HTTPS
- with given credentials for HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS

Native:
- without credentials since you cannot set them when Native

I tried to setup the proxy in my eclipse.ini

Thats the important part of the pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        ...
</project>
```

I expect proxy to be requested when downloading from internet the parent pom.

An alternative could be to somehow put the parent pom into our Sonatype Nexus Repository Managment and download it from there when creating a new Spring-Boot-Starter-Project. Unfortunatly I don't know how.